# Change folder id of an file

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I try to change the id of the file

```
function changeFolder(fileId) {

        var body = {'data-id': fileId};
        var request = gapi.client.drive.files.patch({
            'resource': body
        });
        request.execute(function(resp) {
        getDriveFiles()
    });

}
```

just for testing it

```
changeFolder("ff0BwqgiBZZLvOBTm91bD2448hf")
```

But it keeps ignoring the parameter in it ( Required path parameter fileId is missing )

I did same trick with changing name.(It worked very well)

UPDATE code:

```
function changeFolder(folderId, fileId) {

  var body = {'id': folderId};
  var request = gapi.client.drive.parents.insert({
    'fileId': fileId,
    'resource': body
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) {

   });

}
```

My problem now is that he creates the file at 2 places with same id
I need it to replace/create it in other map and remove the old one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert

you need 2 parameters when of the file id and 1 of the folder id

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the folderId using `Files.patch` as `folderId` is not included in the [File resource properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource). You were successful in changing the title because it's one of the properties listed in the resource.

You can change the folderId of by using the suggested `Parents.insert`  or [inserting the file in a new folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#inserting_a_file_in_a_folder) in v3.

Comment: I can copy it to somewhere else with my updated code. The problem is now i have the file at 2 places

Comment: Yes. that's exactly what's going to happen. so you should delete the former folder so you can use the new folder as main reference. Good job tho